# Получение значения с android context

Tags: java, android, context

Всем привет. Переписываю некоторые методы с android приложения для реализации их чисто на java. Возник вопрос по поводу получения данных с методов приложения:

```
context.getPackageName();
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionName; 
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),64).signatures[0];
```

Можно ли как-то вытащить их чисто как строку для подстановки уже в мои методы на java?

Comment: Как-то не понятно что вы хотите. В десктопной Java нет, ни таких классов/методов, ни того, что они возвращают. То есть, я не вижу смысла переносить код, их использующий.

Comment: оно? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getpackage.htm

Comment: Я понимаю, что в десктопной Java нет таких классов, поэтому и задал вопрос по этому поводу здесь) Данное приложение коннектится к серверу и передает эти данные в строке. Мне же нужно сделать такой же алгоритм на Java и каким-то образом с apk файла вытащить эти данные.

Comment: Вы хотите получить то, что возвращают эти методы, но в коде для Java SE из APK-файла или любыми средствами "подсмотреть" однажды, чтобы захардкодить в java-коде? Не стесняйтесь в подробностях - вопрос можно дополнять и редактировать (кнопкой [`править`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1059614/edit)).Первые два записаны в `AndroidManifest.xml`, но он скомпилирован и нужен специальный парсер (можно найти библиотеки по запросу 'apkparser'). Сам APK - это ZIP-архив, заглянуть и распаковать можно любым архиватором.

Comment: Про сигнатуру гляньте здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558623/how-to-find-signature-of-apk-file. Возможно и всю инфу можно получить какими-то утилитами из SDK.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, вроде то, что нужно)